# Как подключить шифрование?

Tags: c++, c, криптография, openssl

Есть программа на шарпах:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace Crypto
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string DatabaseFilePath = "testCrypto.bin";
            var stream = new FileStream(DatabaseFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            var cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider
            {
                Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH"),
                IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH")
            };
            var crStream = new CryptoStream(stream, cryptic.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Help me stackoverflow!");
            crStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

`CreateEncryptor()` создает `AES-шифрование`. И вот хочется в QT написать программу расшифровки, используя популярные/стандартные/правильные решения. В QT стандартных библиотек шифрования вроде нет. Наткнулся на [openssl](https://github.com/openssl/openssl) и [crypto++](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp), и не могу понять что делать дальше? что скачивать? как использовать?

Comment: Вы задаете слишком общий вопрос - "не могу ничего, как сделать все".

Answer (score 0):

> Наткнулся на openssl и crypto++, и не могу понять что делать дальше?

Дальше — что хочешь... Некоторые распространённые варианты приведены ниже:

- Почитать документацию/примеры, поспрашивай наводящие вопросы у гугла (в меру развития, можно хоть видео туториалы на тытрубе смотреть).
- Стоит выбрать что-то одно. Можно конечно сделать остальные шаги для обеих библиотек и отложить выбор на потом, но когда возникнут конкретные вопросы по обеим расписывать ответы вряд ли кто-то захочет.
- Скачай/установи/собери библиотеки. Под большинство *nix систем это делается штатными средствами, а в некоторых есть даже из коробки. Если нет, то сборка обычно описана в файлах с говорящими названиями `README` или `INSTALL`. Под win* — я хз, так что лишь посоветую вернуться к чтению документации.
- Сделай простенький *hello world*, с помощью своих средств разработки. Как — возвращусь к первому пункту про чтение доков.
- Пользуясь полученным опытом подключай либу к своему проекту.

Answer (score 0):

Инструкция установки openSSL на win.

1. Переходим по ссылке http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
2. Качаем не лайт версию (32 бит пробовал).
3. Во время установки выбираем пункт: `the openssl binaries (/bin) directory`
4. После установки добавляем в переменные среды в переменную `PATH`: `C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib`
5. В .pro-файл проекта на QT добавляем строчку: `INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenSSL-Win32/include`
6. В main.cpp пробуем для примера написать строчку : `#include <openssl/aes.h>` и скомпилировать.
7. Готово